# Ember Component does not reload on route reload or transitionTo

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I have an ember route that calls an ember component to display all the data.

I have a case in which the route's key changes and I reload using `route.transitionTo`. The data is loaded fine. But the problem is the component does stuff in the `init` and `didInsertElement` methods, which on the `route.transitionTo` aren't triggered.

How can I make sure on `transitionTo` the component is called again?

I can't use `route.refresh` because that doesn't do the model hook.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a harder and better way, and there is a lazy and fast way:

1. Better way: I suggest you to create a property in the route and pass this parameter to the component, and in the component create a computed property for that parameter, what you've sent, and there you can run your code what you called in "init" and "didInsertElement" function.

E.g.:
router.hbs

```
{{component-name parameter=parameter}}
```

Component.js

```
lineWidth: Ember.computed('parameter', function() {
    // I will run here if I get the parameter (and the parameter changed in route)
}),
```

2. Not the best way:
   You can reload the whole component like this:

router.hbs

```
{{#if reload}}
    {{component-name}}
{{/if}}
```

router.js

```
this.set('reload', false);
Ember.run.next(() => {
    this.set('reload', true);
});
```

Comment: I already went with the first option, it works. But it just doesn't feel right that I have to put a listener for it, was hoping for a cleaner option. Second is too much. But thank you for taking the time out!